# Does drinking water affect oral thermometer accuracy?

Tags: food, temperature

According to various sources (including [Mayo](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/fever/in-depth/thermometers/art-20046737) and [Cleveland](http://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/articles/how-to-take-your-temperature) Clinics), one must wait a certain number of minutes before an accurate oral temperature reading may be taken. However, these two sources (and others) seem to disagree on the duration of this wait. In this case, the different is three fold.

When attempting to get an accurate reading of an oral temperature, what external forces play a part in the actual temperature of the tissue in the mouth, how long would it actually take for any small amount of residual tap water to assimilate its temperature to that of the mouth and body temperature, and how long does it actually take for the tissue in the mouth to fully return to normal after drinking room temperature water?